# Why my server's "Load average" is 5, while the cpu is not busy?

Tags: centos5

Why my server's "Load average" is 5, while the cpu is not busy?

anybody know how to fix that issue? what would be the reason? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably iowait. From the Wikipedia article on "load average":

Most UNIX systems count only processes in the running (on CPU) or runnable (waiting for CPU) states. However, Linux also includes processes in uninterruptible sleep states (usually waiting for disk activity), which can lead to markedly different results if many processes remain blocked in I/O due to a busy or stalled I/O system.